# Filter a number of javascript objects using an array of values for one key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, underscore.js

I want to filter the following objects by category_id using the following array of category_id values:

```
[19012000, 19012001, 19012002, 19012003, 19012004, 19012005, 19012006, 19012007, 19012008] 



Object {_account: "mjj9jp92z2fD1mLlpQYZI1gAd4q4LwTKmBNLz", _id: "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61", amount: 15, category: Array[2], category_id: "13005015"…}
Object {_account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj", _id: "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB", amount: 50, category: Array[3], category_id: "19012000"…}
Object {_account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj", _id: "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK", amount: 24, category: Array[2], category_id: "13005007"…}
Object {_account: "mjj9jp92z2fD1mLlpQYZI1gAd4q4LwTKmBNLz", _id: "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61", amount: 45, category: Array[2], category_id: "13005009"…}
Object {_account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj", _id: "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB", amount: 105, category: Array[3], category_id: "13005009"…}
```

When finished the object with category_id 19012000 should be the only one left.

```
Object {_account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj", _id: "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB", amount: 50, category: Array[3], category_id: "19012000"…}
```

I've made a number of attempts with different versions of iteratee functions with filter, map and each and tried key value filters with keys, values, invert, pick and omit. After trying this, which I believe should work I reach out to you:

```
var postDate = _.filter(_.first(goodDates), function(n){return category_id.indexOf(n.category_id) !== -1})
```

where goodDates is the list of objects and category_id is the array above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf()` with a string and a number

```
var a = [123]; 
console.log(a.indexOf(123));  //true   
console.log(a.indexOf("123"));  //false
```

Your code is not working because you are comparing a string in your object to the numbers in your array.

```
category_id.indexOf(+n.category_id)
```

or

```
category_id.indexOf(parseInt(n.category_id, 10))
```

Comment: Wow! I woulda never saw that. It has to be part of the problem. Still, I cut in paste your code giving me: 

_.filter(_.first(goodDates), function(n){return category_id.indexOf(+n.category_id) !== -1})

just to be thorough I also tried

_.filter(_.first(goodDates), function(n){return category_id.indexOf(+n.category_id)})

_.filter(_.first(goodDates), function(n){return category_id.indexOf(parseInt(n.category_id, 10))) !== -1})

_.filter(_.first(goodDates), function(n){return category_id.indexOf(parseInt(n.category_id, 10))})

Still I only received a list of empty arrays []

Comment: Thanks a million. I ended up reverting back to a previous version using a for loop and if statement. Thanks to you teasing out that detail I was able to make it work this time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use [`_.first`](http://underscorejs.org/#first) here? The rest of your filter statement looks good, altough you may swap the `indexOf` call for [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains):

```
var postDates = _.filter(goodDates, function(n){
    return _.contains(category_id, n.category_id);
});
```

Comment: _.first is because each object comes wrapped in an array from a previous query.  _.first(goodDates) is the object shown above.  I'm going to try your suggestion now.

Comment: That returns a number of empty arrays []
I'm using underscore 1.7. I think it must be active because _.find, _.map, _.extend, _.groupBy  in different places throughout this JS file.

Comment: Uh, in your OP you didn't say anything about the objects being wrapped in arrays, you just stated "*goodDates is the list of objects*". Actually posting `goodDates` as JSON would help to clear that up.

Comment: It's OK, I have that part under control. _.first(goodDates) is the object you see above; I ran the precedent to goodDates through a loop and pushed the results into an array so I used _.first to get each of loop results out of the array. I'm only concerned with filtering the objects to take out all of the objects save for ones that have category_id in the array. epascarello astutely pointed out that one of the issues is that category_id in the object is text and in the array is a number.